# Same request works in Fiddler but not in Requets

Tags: python, http, python-requests, instagram

I'm trying to edit my Instagram Bio from Python using requests. I can easily log in and do follows/etc but I am stuck at editing profile. I keep getting either 403 error or 400. When I pretty print my Python raw request, it looks like this (These are cookies of my dummy account):

```
POST https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/58.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.instagram.com
Content-Length: 131
Origin: https://www.instagram.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-CSRFToken: buJOTJT8lR2XcTL6WU5G9Rviq3mjmhaa
X-Instagram-AJAX: 314b21580dde
DNT: 1
Referer: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/
Accept-Language: et-EE,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6
Cookie: mid=W1WlVQALAAEfLNtIlXn2CtR3XAUF; ig_cb=1; mcd=3; 
ds_user_id=8271265936; 
sessionid=IGSCad223c2888974f0472cea36f3
16b1d3caab2feaa3bf519fa3652da183dca2446%3 
ARItc316HmDIUvwjI8BOJCzyvuFkHbeXd%3A%7B%
22_auth_user_id%22%3A8271265936%2C%22_aut 
h_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.
CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%
22%3A%22%22%2C%22_platform%
22%3A4%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_tok
en%22%3A%228271265936%3AXMCx3bjvUtWEy3A37
cDnQiQ9ysQBaGw9%3A5aaef5c33915c937439a14292
048d8ae0555d5bf949befcd5a9a8a209808e7c9%22%2C%22
last_refreshed%22%3A1532306445.48 
36139679%7D; rur=PRN; urlgen="{"time": 1532295222, "88.196.120.23": 3249, 
"2001:7d0:8b1b:d80:59ac:b6fd:fc77:754f": 
3249}:1fhOwz:lMzBvH8bTYwoOqWauglUMXbkGCU
```

And the body of my POST data:

```
 first_name=888&email=ml162uju%40email.org&
 username=6relvwyv&phone_number=&gender=1&biography
 =&external_url=&chaining_enabled=on400
```

When I send this exact request through fiddler It works, I get 200, but through Python i get 403 or 400. I tried sending data as raw string and as a dict but both return error.

Code:

```
    self.s = requests.Session()
    self.s.cookies.clear()
    self.s.headers.update({'Host': 'www.instagram.com',
                            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                            'Content-Length': '136',
                            'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            'Accept': '*/*',
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0',
                            'X-CSRFToken': 'buJOTJT8lR2XcTL6WU5G9Rviq3mjmhaa',
                            'X-Instagram-AJAX': '314b21580dde',
                            'DNT': '1',
                            'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/',
                            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                            'Accept-Language': 'et-EE,et;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6',
                            'Cookie': """mid=W1WlVQALAAEfLNtIlXn2CtR3XAUF; ig_cb=1; mcd=3; ds_user_id=8271265936; sessionid=IGSCad223c2888974f0472cea36f316b1d3caab2feaa3bf519fa3652da183dca2446%3ARItc316HmDIUvwjI8BOJCzyvuFkHbeXd%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A8271265936%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%228271265936%3AXMCx3bjvUtWEy3A37cDnQiQ9ysQBaGw9%3A5aaef5c33915c937439a14292048d8ae0555d5bf949befcd5a9a8a209808e7c9%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1532306445.4836139679%7D; rur=PRN; urlgen="{\"time\": 1532295222\054 \"88.196.120.23\": 3249\054 \"2001:7d0:8b1b:d80:59ac:b6fd:fc77:754f\": 3249}:1fhOwz:lMzBvH8bTYwoOqWauglUMXbkGCU"""
    })
    r = self.s.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/?__a=1')
    data = r.json()
    self.form = data['form_data']
    data_x = {'first_name': self.check(first_name, 'first_name'),
            'email': self.check(email, 'email'),
            'username': self.check(username, 'username'),
            'phone_number': self.check(phone_number, 'phone_number'),
            'gender': '3',
            'biography': self.check(biography, 'biography'),
            'external_url': self.check(external_url, 'external_url'),
            'chaining_enabled': 'on'
    }

    r = self.s.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/', data=data_x)
    print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: can you share the python code where you call requests

Comment: I edited my post to include code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and pass the cookies to the request module as well as in headers (try with and without)

```
import http.cookies

str_cookies = """mid=W1WlVQALAAEfLNtIlXn2CtR3XAUF; ig_cb=1; mcd=3; ds_user_id=8271265936; sessionid=IGSCad223c2888974f0472cea36f316b1d3caab2feaa3bf519fa3652da183dca2446%3ARItc316HmDIUvwjI8BOJCzyvuFkHbeXd%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A8271265936%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%228271265936%3AXMCx3bjvUtWEy3A37cDnQiQ9ysQBaGw9%3A5aaef5c33915c937439a14292048d8ae0555d5bf949befcd5a9a8a209808e7c9%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1532306445.4836139679%7D; rur=PRN; urlgen="{\"time\": 1532295222\054 \"88.196.120.23\": 3249\054 \"2001:7d0:8b1b:d80:59ac:b6fd:fc77:754f\": 3249}:1fhOwz:lMzBvH8bTYwoOqWauglUMXbkGCU"""\
cookie_object = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(str_cookies)
cookies = {}
for key, morsel in cookie_object.items():
    cookies[key] = morsel.value

requests.post(.... , cookies=cookies)
```

I suggest you use this [instagram_private_api](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api) python module which has implemented most of the methods you may need instead of building it yourself

Comment: Okay, I took your code and instead of using session I passed session headers into my request separately and it worked! It just doesn't work when I call same request with my session, which is odd. Marked as answer, thanks!

Comment: thats cool. You can use `session` but pass the cookies as a separate argument and not just in the headers